# Neo4j throwing Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionHookFailed when Cypher is executed

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

Please can you please point what's wrong with this cypher statement because when the statement is executed, the database is throwing TransactionHookFailed error. Also, it might help if you can explain the meaning of this error.

```
MATCH (user:User { id: $userId })
MATCH (event:Event { id: $eventId })-[:BOUND_TO_EXPIRE]->(expiryDate)
WITH user, event, apoc.nodes.connected(user, event, 'ORGANIZED>') AS isOrganizer, expiryDate
// Make sure the user is the organizer of the event
WHERE isOrganizer = true
// Just delete event
DETACH DELETE expiryDate
DETACH DELETE event
// Remove event from the user's event
SET user.noOfEvents = user.noOfEvents - 1
RETURN {
  clientResponse: true
}
```

Comment: do you have a stacktrace in your debug.log file ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error

`Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionHookFailed`

because a constraint on the database required certain fields to be set when updating a node. I was setting other fields but not the required ones.

Perhaps your database has constraints on it as well.

You would get a syntax error if the cypher code was bad, so that's probably not the case.